# Why do volumes appear more dense when sliced with a bunch of transparent planes?

Tags: shaders, volumetrics

I encountered a very weird behavior with my procedural clouds. For context, I also used VDB clouds, which were full of artifacts where they are intersecting with each other. I found a hacky workaround to this issue, which is to place a ton of transparent planes inside the volume.

Now, as I forgot to hide these planes, I turned on the procedural clouds, and noticed how they appeared completely differently.

Without planes:

[image]

With planes:

[image]

You can see how these planes are placed in the scene. What also confuses me, is that originally I had a multiply node to increase the density of the clouds, but it didn't really appear to be doing anything. But with these transparent planes, it seems to work as intended.

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Edit:
volume bounces: 2
transparent bounces: 120
volume step rate: 1
volume max steps: 8

Answer (score 1):

Missing some details here, shaders and light path settings would be useful.

Some experimentation tells me that a transparent plane using Principled BSDF has odd behavior, I'm guessing because it has a lot of surface components in addition to transmission.  If you use Transparent BSDF it should be different.

Other potential causes:

Light Paths -> Volumes is default 0

Clamped Indirect Lighting

Step count or step size in volume settings?

Comment: Added these info to the post. I'm using the transparent shader.

Comment: Of course setting _Transmission_ > 0 on a _Principled BSDF_ behaves differently than a _Transparent BSDF_. Transmission makes the _Principled BSDF_ work like glass and takes the IOR into account and still has reflections, a _Transparent BSDF_ creates alpha transparency (with the difference that you can color it i.e. give the RGB channels individual alpha values). Fully transparent becomes invisible, fully transmissive not.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann you're right, I was just tooling around at work while I was on break and breaking the rules on BSE.  Hello, btw, feels like a while since I've seen you but I'm sure you've been around

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann fwiw I did set IOR and it didn't solve the apparent problem of cutting light to volumes or whatever was happening in my test file.  It was a long day, lol.  Question just says 'transparent planes' and I was trying to determine what that meant

Comment: Yeah hello, actually when I saw some of your recent posts yesterday I also got the feeling it's been a while :-)

Comment: Transparent planes are self explanetory. Planes that are transparent :p not sure how else to explain it.